# Windows 8.1 stuck at “preparing Windows”

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, temporary-files

After removing temporay files, including windows update backups (it was more than 30 GB!), by means of the built-in tool, I cannot access my pc any more: it is stuck on a blue page that says “Preparing Windows, don’t shut down”.  How can I solve the problem?

Comment: How long has it been at this screen? I can take a long time, be patient.

Comment: And hopefully you removed the temporary files **after** the updates were applied, after rebooting directly to Windows, not to a partial update operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. After waiting almost two hours, the computer rebooted and came back to normal working conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, which is not necessarily the general answer to the post question, I just had to wait almost two hours. After that, the computer rebooted and came back to normal working conditions.